# Passing a value from fullCalendar click to Django template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, fullcalendar, django-urls

I'm trying to pass an event id from FullCalendar to Django template as an argument to url resolver. I'm using Django 1.8 and Twitter Bootstrap.

In my `views.py`, I have `view_shifts(request)` which renders `calendar_init.html` with appropriate context.

This is what my calendar_init.html roughly looks like.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Shifts {% endblock %}
{% block extra_head %}

// links for fullCalendar, jQuery, and Bootstrap

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { // Page is now ready.
        // Initialize the calendar.
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // headers and other settings
            eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="fullCalForm" method="post" action="{% url 'shifts:sell' shiftId %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                    <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-shift-id="shift_id_value" class="btn btn-primary">Sell</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>
                    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary"><a id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a></button>-->
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="calendar"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="calendar"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

The part I'm having problem with is `shiftId` of `<form class="fullCalForm" method="post" action="{% url 'shifts:sell' shiftId %}">`. I need to pass the id of the shift (a fullCalendar event) for the `sell` function in `views.py`, which takes `shift_id` as an argument. When I put `100` as a test instead of shiftId, the whole thing works as expected. I'm just not sure how to retrieve the id of the event and pass that as an argument in place of shiftId.

I've been pulling my hair for a while about this. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**: Thanks to Daniel's comment, I was able to tweak the code around a bit to make more sense. I'm still having trouble getting the right value of `shiftId`, however. I'm not sure how to put the id into a hidden field and retrieve it from the `sell` function.

After edits, my code looks like the following:

```
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
    ...
    <form class="fullCalForm" method="post" action="{% url 'shifts:sell' %}">
    ...
    </form>
</div>
```

and in `views.py`, my `sell` function:

```
def sell(request):
    shift = get_object_or_404(Shift, pk=request.POST['shiftId']) # Obviously 
                                        # not working, not sure how to fix it..
    sale = Sale.objects.create(shift=shift, seller=request.user, datetime_sold=datetime.now)
    shift.on_sale = not shift.on_sale
    shift.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('shifts:view_shifts'))
```

Comment: This is very unclear, unfortunately. Where is `shiftId` coming from? Is it passed into the template context from the view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, I wasn't sure how to make the question clearer. shiftId is just a temporary placeholder, and the right value should be coming from fullCalendar's `event.id` of the chosen event. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way. The `url` tag is evaluated when the template is processed, at request time, on the server. `shiftId` needs to be defined at that point, and you can't change it directly after that. FullCalendar is a javascript library, and runs on the client, by which time there is no `url` tag, there is just a generated URL.

So, if you want something happening in fullCalendar to affect the form that is submitted to, you need to do one of two things. One would be to prepopulate that URL with a placeholder which you know is never going to be valid - "00000", say - and get your JS to replace that value with the real value of shiftId where necessary.

The other, which I think is probably better, would be to remove the parameter from the URL altogether, and put it into a hidden form field, which will be submitted alongside the rest of the data.

**Edit**

I don't know anything about the fullCalendar API, but I guess `eventClick` is a list of callbacks that are executed when you click on the event. So we would need to add an empty hidden field in your HTML, and a callback to populate it in eventClick.

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    ...
    $('#clientIdField').val(event.id);
}

<form class="fullCalForm" method="post" action="{% url 'shifts:sell' %}">
  <input type="hidden" name="client_id" id="clientIdField">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes lots of sense. How would I put shiftId as a hidden form field and make sure it's passed to the `sell(request, shiftId)` function when the function is called?

Comment: You shouldn't, you should change the view to just be `sell(request)` and get shiftId from `request.POST['shift_id']` or wherever.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying. I feel like I'm much closer now. Would you mind looking at my edit for a bit more guidance?